# How does Vagrant setup network interfaces?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine

As I understand,network interface is a software interface to networking hardware.
On my Vagrant VM

```
 ifconfig
cni0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1450
        inet 10.42.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.42.0.255
        inet6 fe80::701f:eeff:fe1d:d6e6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 72:1f:ee:3d:d6:e6  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 25121  bytes 5779617 (5.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 27525  bytes 5015563 (5.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:5f:22:da:4b  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255
        inet6 fe80::31:13ff:fe65:d89d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:31:13:65:d8:9d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 493221  bytes 724779493 (724.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 67519  bytes 4607813 (4.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp0s8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.33.10  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.33.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fef5:15c2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:f5:35:c2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 25  bytes 1946 (1.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

flannel.1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1450
        inet 10.42.0.0  netmask 255.255.255.255  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        inet6 fe80::f811:e6ff:fe7a:ac62  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fa:11:e6:7a:ac:74  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 5 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

How does VM create them? What is the difference between `enp0s3` and `enp0s8`?